# How to get invoice details for modern CSP (CSP Azure Plan)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-sdk-.net, azure-billing-api

I want to show cost management details so for that i need to get invoice details for Modern CSP (Azure Plan). So can someone tell me is there any API or .Net SDK available to get details.